# How can I output this special matrix?

Tags: matrices, block

I want to output a special matrix like this:
[image]

But, I don't know how to do this.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried?

Comment: Do you have any code to show, yet? Please provide an MWE and we can work on it. When you will have worked out an MWE, rephrase your quesion to make it more specific. The block tag look misplaced, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose three variant: in display style, medium size (with the `\medmath`command from `nccmath` – ca 80 % of display style) and supposedly text style with the `psmallmatrix(*)` defined by `mathtools`. Of course, with four rows, this will enlarge the line spacing locally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
A' = \begin{pmatrix}
 & & & & & & & 0\\
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\smash{\huge$A$}}} & 0 \\[-1.5ex]
 & & & & & & & ⋮ \\
 0 & 0 & \hdotsfor{5} &0
\end{pmatrix}
\] 

\[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
A' = \medmath{\begin{pmatrix}
 & & & & & & & 0\\
 \multicolumn{7}{c}{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\smash{\Large$A$}}} & 0 \\[-1.5ex]
 & & & & & & & ⋮ \\[-0.5ex]
 0 & 0 & \hdotsfor{5} \!&0
\end{pmatrix}}
\]

Some text. Some more text. An in-text matrix $ A' = \begin{psmallmatrix}
 & & & & 0\\[0.5ex]
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\smash{\large$A$}}} & 0 \\[-2.3ex]
 & & & & \vdots \\[0.4ex]
 0 & 0 & \!\hdots\! &\! \hdots\! & 0
\end{psmallmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's OK. But it' s too big, I want it be small and can output among the text. I replaced the pmatrix  by smallmatrix, but I failed. Can you help me again? THKS

Comment: @chenchen: I've added two variants to the initial code.  Please see if it's more like you want.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots/shorten=6pt}

\begin{document}

\[
A' = 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[left-margin=1pt]
\Block[borders={bottom,right},line-width=0.2pt]{3-3}<\Huge>{A}
&&& 0 \\
&&& 0 \\
&&& \Vdots \\
0 &  0 & \Ldots & 0 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]